# issue in report generation using jasperReport

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2

Hi am new to struts and jsp technology, please help me overcome this error !!!!

Question : I have a jsp page with url as , `var url = '<s:url action=" "/>?branchId=' '&financialYear=' '` .

And I am trying to generating a pdf report using jasperReport, but at report generation time the URL contains `branchId` and `financialYear` also (like :http://localhost:8086/casba-pa-war/at/8017_gr.action?branchId=301&financialYear=2016-2017).

Can I generate a report without `branchId` and `financialYear`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You can use POST.

Comment: The report generation might require additional parameters